# Stats Models Logit().fit() function throwing an error LinAlgError: Singular matrix

Tags: python, python-3.x, statistics, statsmodels

I am trying to to create run a logit model on a dataset where mpg_high is the outcome variable based on the other data frame columns.

When I run the following code I do not get any errors:

```
exog = ['constant','cylinders','displacement','horsepower','weight','year', 'origin']

logit = sm.Logit(endog = df_quant2['mpg_high'], exog = df_quant2[['constant','cylinders','displacement','horsepower','weight','year', 'origin']])
```

but when i try to use

```
logit.fit()
```

I get the following error:

```
Warning: Maximum number of iterations has been exceeded.
         Current function value: inf
         Iterations: 35


/Users/*/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/statsmodels/discrete/discrete_model.py:1214: RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in exp
  return 1/(1+np.exp(-X))
/Users/*/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/statsmodels/discrete/discrete_model.py:1264: RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in log
  return np.sum(np.log(self.cdf(q*np.dot(X,params))))
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
LinAlgError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-112-f8dd482d7884> in <module>()
----> 1 logit.fit()

/Users/*/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/statsmodels/discrete/discrete_model.py in fit(self, start_params, method, maxiter, full_output, disp, callback, **kwargs)
   1375         bnryfit = super(Logit, self).fit(start_params=start_params,
   1376                 method=method, maxiter=maxiter, full_output=full_output,
-> 1377                 disp=disp, callback=callback, **kwargs)
   1378 
   1379         discretefit = LogitResults(self, bnryfit)

/Users/*/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/statsmodels/discrete/discrete_model.py in fit(self, start_params, method, maxiter, full_output, disp, callback, **kwargs)
    202         mlefit = super(DiscreteModel, self).fit(start_params=start_params,
    203                 method=method, maxiter=maxiter, full_output=full_output,
--> 204                 disp=disp, callback=callback, **kwargs)
    205 
    206         return mlefit # up to subclasses to wrap results

/Users/*/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/statsmodels/base/model.py in fit(self, start_params, method, maxiter, full_output, disp, fargs, callback, retall, skip_hessian, **kwargs)
    456             Hinv = cov_params_func(self, xopt, retvals)
    457         elif method == 'newton' and full_output:
--> 458             Hinv = np.linalg.inv(-retvals['Hessian']) / nobs
    459         elif not skip_hessian:
    460             H = -1 * self.hessian(xopt)

/Users/*/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/linalg/linalg.py in inv(a)
    511     signature = 'D->D' if isComplexType(t) else 'd->d'
    512     extobj = get_linalg_error_extobj(_raise_linalgerror_singular)
--> 513     ainv = _umath_linalg.inv(a, signature=signature, extobj=extobj)
    514     return wrap(ainv.astype(result_t, copy=False))
    515 

/Users/*/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/linalg/linalg.py in _raise_linalgerror_singular(err, flag)
     88 
     89 def _raise_linalgerror_singular(err, flag):
---> 90     raise LinAlgError("Singular matrix")
     91 
     92 def _raise_linalgerror_nonposdef(err, flag):

LinAlgError: Singular matrix
```

All the values in the mpg_high values are either 0 or 1

Not sure what I am missing here, appreciate any help!

Thanks!

Comment: Based on the warning I would try to increase maxiter and see if it converges in that case. The other issue to check is if you didn't run into the dummy variable trap and created a singular design matrix `exog`. Models with nonlinear optimization cannot handle singular design matrices or singular hessian.

Answer (score 0):

***UPDATE***

I was able to get some of the model working by excluding the Horsepower variable from the endog arguments. It may have been due to the data type. I have sinced converted it to a float64 but the model still will not run with the now changed column data type

Comment: I think it will help if you print out the entire data frame (I'm guessing it's not too large) and also say exactly what is the error you're getting now.